# Replace multiple instances of the same string with different UUIDs

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a file with some text in it. That text contains multiple UUIDs that I need to generate dynamically; something like this:

```html
Some text: [UUID]
Some other text: [UUID]
More text: [UUID] [UUID]
```

I want to replace each `[UUID]` with a different, random UUID. This is what I have so far (the `some_text` variable contains the above text):

```yaml
"{{ some_text | replace('[UUID]', ( lookup('community.general.random_string') | to_uud ) ) }}"
```

This does fine at generating a random UUID and replacing the text, but it replaces *all* instances of `[UUID]` with the same individual UUID. How would I generate a new UUID for *each* instance of `[UUID]`?

I was thinking I could add a number to the replace string in the source file like this:

```html
Some text: [UUID0]
Some other text: [UUID1]
More text: [UUID2] [UUID3]
```

Then use `with_sequence: 0-3` to loop through each instance, but that's tedious and would require continually incrementing the number if UUID's need to be added/removed from the source file. It seems there should be a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to modify the file in place, you can read it in, process it line by line, and then write out the result. Something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: read file
      command: cat data.txt
      register: data

    - name: replace uuid tokens
      copy:
        dest: data.txt
        content: |
          {% for line in data.stdout_lines %}
          {{ line.replace('[UUID]', lookup('community.general.random_string') | to_uuid) }}
          {% endfor %}
```

Given an input file that looks like:

```
Some text: [UUID]
Some other text: [UUID]
More text: [UUID] [UUID]
```

The output might look like:

```
Some text: b252be6d-70d9-5b62-a4cb-4ef04b06c6e7
Some other text: f28cfdf3-7c92-55f7-b597-50e635f99b38
More text: 2572da88-cdc5-5e6a-ada5-e53556a3e5c9 2572da88-cdc5-5e6a-ada5-e53556a3e5c9
```